# In this example, why are the points exterior to the circle $|z|=1$ mapped onto the nonzero points interior to it?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

On page $314$ it says "the points exterior to the circle $|z|=1$ mapped onto the nonzero points interior to it".

**Why/How is this so?**

From Complex Variables - Churchill/Brown
[image]

Comment: Because $| {1 \over z}| = {1 \over |z|}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|z|>1$, then $|1/z|=1/|z|<1$, so the point outside the unit disk got moved inside, but not to zero since $1/z\neq 0$ for any $z$. Conversely, if $0<|z|<1$, then $|1/z|=1/|z|>1$. If $|z|=1$, then $$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{\overline z}{z\overline z}=\frac{\overline z}{|z|^2}=\overline z.$$ So points on the circle are mapped to their complex-conjugates, which also lies on the unit circle.